# Generate a unique link for each name - yii2

Tags: php, database, yii, yii2

I am working on development of web app, Users are supposed to register on the web app.
This is my table where data is being stored post registration.
[image: My table]

I would like to give every user a unique url which would be stored in the same table where details of the users is being saved so that their profile url shares their society name (society_name). For example, the website domain would be [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and the users' url would be [www.example.com/mysociety](http://www.example.com/mysociety)

I would like to save the unique  generated url in  in the field "url"(#14) of my table.

My User Register Controller looks like this

```
public function actionRegister() {
    $this->layout = 'society';
    
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    
    $model = new User();
    $society = new \app\models\Society();
    
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        
    $password= $_POST['User']['password'];
    $password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    $auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    
    $mobile=$_POST['User']['mobile'];
    $society = new \app\models\Society();
    $random_number=mt_rand(10000, 99999);
    $society->society_name = $_POST['Society']['society_name'];
    $society->contact_person = $_POST['Society']['contact_person']; 
    $society->address = $_POST['Society']['address'];       
    $society->society_id =$random_number;
    $society->mobile = $mobile;
    $society->status =0;
    $society->save();
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    return $this->redirect(['regsuccess']);
    }  
    return $this->render('society', [
                'model' => $model,
                'society' => $society,
   ]);}
```

PS : English is not my native language. I am newbie to yii2 and stackoverflow, please excuse me for the mistakes.
Thanks.

Comment: You can store it as `$model->url = ...` then `$model->save()` But I this would create problems in the future, what happens if you update the domain name? Or migrate the code to a module, migrate to a subdomain, or even update the company's name! It seems like it would be better to update the structure of the data, then use Yii's URL manager to dynamically generate and parse the URLs for you.

Comment: Also, it looks like you store `society_name` on the user's table, that probably does not belong there, especially if you already have it on the `society` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

> Modified my Controller

```
public function actionRegister() {
$this->layout = 'society';
if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    return $this->goHome();
}


$model = new User();
$society = new \app\models\Society();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
$password= $_POST['User']['password'];
$password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
$auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
$mobile=$_POST['User']['mobile'];
$society = new \app\models\Society();
$random_number=mt_rand(10000, 99999);
$vp_string = trim($_POST['Society']['society_name']);

$vp_string = html_entity_decode($vp_string);

$vp_string = strip_tags($vp_string);

$vp_string = strtolower($vp_string);

$vp_string = preg_replace('[^ a-z0-9_\.]', ' ', $vp_string);

$vp_string = preg_replace('~ ~', '-', $vp_string);
$society->society_name = $_POST['Society']['society_name'];
$society->contact_person = $_POST['Society']['contact_person']; 
$society->address = $_POST['Society']['address'];       
$society->society_id =$random_number;
$society->mobile = $mobile;
$society->url = $vp_string;
$society->status =0;
$society->save();
$session = Yii::$app->session;
return $this->redirect(['regsuccess']);
}  
return $this->render('society', [
            'model' => $model,
            'society' => $society,
```

]);}